# Assigning maxtrix from scipy.sparse.identity to csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I want to assign a large scale `scipy.sparse.identity` to a slice of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` but am failing to do so. In this case, `m = 25000000` and `p=3`. `Tc_temp` is the `csr_matrix` of size `25000000 x 75000000`.

```
Tc_temp = csr_matrix((m, p * m))
Tc_temp[0: m, np.arange(j, p * m + j, p)] = identity(m, format='csr')
```

The error traceback I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\kusari\Miniconda3\envs\cvxpy_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\_index.py", line 116, in __setitem__
    self._set_arrayXarray_sparse(i, j, x)
  File "C:\Users\kusari\Miniconda3\envs\cvxpy_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 816, in _set_arrayXarray_sparse
    self._zero_many(*self._swap((row, col)))
  File "C:\Users\kusari\Miniconda3\envs\cvxpy_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 932, in _zero_many
    i, j, M, N = self._prepare_indices(i, j)
  File "C:\Users\kusari\Miniconda3\envs\cvxpy_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 882, in _prepare_indices
    i = np.array(i, dtype=self.indices.dtype, copy=False, ndmin=1).ravel()
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 233. GiB for an array with shape (62500000000,) and data type int32
```

The `sparse.identity` is somehow getting converted to dense matrix.

Comment: how about creating the matrix from scratch using `coo` style inputs?

Comment: Digging into the traceback code it looks like error occurs while "clearing" space in `Tc_temp` for the (m,m) block.  The error occurs when creating the (m**2) row index array.  It hasn't even touched the `identify` matrix (except to convert it to `coo` format).  Also it expands the `0:m` to `arange(m)[:,None]`, It's doing its own version of broadcasted 'advanced' indexing.  This is far too general and complicated for your needs.

Comment: `csr` docs and code warns about doing indexed assignment.  I thought the warnings were meant to discourage repeated assignments, but even a single large one is expensive.  `lil` format is supposed to be better for assignment, though I don't know if it would handle these dimensions any better.  It is best to create a `csr` matrix directly from `coo` style inputs (or the `csr` indptr style if you understand that).  Don't think in terms of modifying an initially "empty" matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's examine the action for a smaller matrix:

The identity - in coo format:

```
In [67]: I = sparse.identity(10,format='coo')
In [68]: I.row
Out[68]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
In [69]: I.col
Out[69]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
```

The "blank" csr:

```
In [70]: M = sparse.csr_matrix((10,30))
In [71]: M.indptr
Out[71]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
In [72]: M.indices
Out[72]: array([], dtype=int32)
```

The assignment.  I'm using slice notation here rather than your `arange`, but the effect is the same (even in timings):

```
In [73]: M[0:10, 0:30:3] = I
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/_index.py:116: SparseEfficiencyWarning: Changing the sparsity structure of a csr_matrix is expensive. lil_matrix is more efficient.
  self._set_arrayXarray_sparse(i, j, x)
```

The resulting matrix:

```
In [74]: M.indptr
Out[74]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10], dtype=int32)
In [75]: M.indices
Out[75]: array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27], dtype=int32)
```

And look at the coresponding `coo` attributes:

```
In [76]: M.tocoo().row
Out[76]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], dtype=int32)
In [77]: M.tocoo().col
Out[77]: array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27], dtype=int32)
```

The `row` is the same as for `I`, while the `col` is just your `arange` indexing:

```
In [78]: np.arange(0,30,3)
Out[78]: array([ 0,  3,  6,  9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27])
```

So you could create the same matrix with:

```
M1 = sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones(10),(np.arange(10), np.arange(0,30,3))),(10,30))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assignment to sparse matrices isn't efficient. It builds a row/column index of the size of your insert. Obviously at this scale that is not viable.

You can work around it though by fiddling directly with the data in a coordinate matrix, although it won't be efficient.

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, identity
import numpy as np

m = 25000000
p = 3
j = 0

Tc_temp = csr_matrix((m, p * m)).tocoo()
Tc_identity = identity(m, format='coo')

# If you know Tc_temp is already 0s where you want to do assignments, you can omit this
# It's gonna be slow if there's a lot of data in Tc_temp
Tc_zero_idx = np.isin(Tc_temp.row, Tc_identity.row) & np.isin(Tc_temp.col, Tc_identity.col * p)
Tc_temp.data[Tc_zero_idx] = 0

# Add the identity matrix to your data
Tc_temp.row = np.append(Tc_temp.row, Tc_identity.row)
Tc_temp.col = np.append(Tc_temp.col, Tc_identity.col * p)
Tc_temp.data = np.append(Tc_temp.data, Tc_identity.data)

Tc_temp.tocsr()
```

Normally I'd tell you to build it block-wise but if you're trying to interleave rows and columns that's not a great option for you.